# Two different ways to solve the same probability exercise

Tags: probability

An urn has 2 white, 2 red and 3 black balls. 2 balls are drawn at random, one at a time and without replacement. Let X be the random variable that counts the number of black balls drawn.

Calculate $P(X = k|B_1)$ for $k ∈ \{0, 1, 2\}$, where $B_1$ is the event "first white ball drawn"

**I have the following solution:**

Let $N_k$ be the event: "k black balls have been drawn"
$P(X = 0|B_1) = \frac{P(\{X=0\}∩B_1)}{P(B_1)} = \frac{P(B_1∩N_2^c)}{P(B_1)} = P(N_2^c|B_1)=\frac{3}{6}=\frac{1}{2} \\
P(X=1|B_1) = \frac{P(\{X=1\}∩B_1)}{P(B_1)}= \frac{P\{B_1∩N_2\}}{P(B_1)} = P(N_2|B_1) = \frac{3}{6}=\frac{1}{2}\\
P(X=2|B_1) = \frac{P(\{X=2∩B_1\})}{P(B_1)} = 0\text{ because } \{X=2\}∩ B_1 = ∅$

Note that the value$ P(B_1) = \frac{2}{7}$it is not essential to do the calculations.

**My question**

Let's take the case $P(X=1|B_1)$ and let's calculate it considering $ P(B_1) = \frac{2}{7}$. For convenience we call $X=1 : X_1$ We have that:

$P(X_1|B_1) = \frac{P(X_1∩B_1)}{P(B_1)} = \frac{P(B_1|X_1)P(X_1)}{P(B_1)} = \frac{\frac{2}{6}\frac{3}{7}}{\frac{2}{7}} = \frac{3}{6}= \frac{1}{2}$

This is because we consider $P(B_1|X_1)$ in this way: "Knowing that a black ball has been drawn, what is the probability that a white ball will be drawn?".The result seems to coincide with the solution of this case.

Now let's consider this other case:$P(X = 0|B1)$. With a reasoning similar to the previous one we are going to write:

$P(X_0|B_1) = \frac{P(X_0∩B_1)}{P(B_1)} = \frac{P(B_1|X_0)P(X_0)}{P(B_1)} = \frac{\frac{2}{4}P(X_0)}{\frac{2}{7}}=...$

Here I don't know how to continue. I don't know what value to assign to $P(X_0)$.Theoretically this represents the probability that no black ball will be drawn. So this should be the complementary event to the one where all three black balls are drawn. How can it be written $P(X_0)$?. So that the overall result is $\frac{1}{2}$.

For completeness, I also write the reasoning that led me to write the result of this $P(B_1|X_0)$:

$P(B_1|X_0)$ represents the following condition: Knowing that no black ball has been drawn, what is the probability that a white ball will be drawn first?
Answer: knowing that no black ball has been drawn, I have to remove the three black balls from the total. Therefore $7 - 3 = 4$. Since there are therefore 2 white balls, I have two chances out of four that they will be drawn. So $\frac{2}{4} = \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: It's not clear what "first white ball drawn" means here. Does it mean that of the two balls that were drawn, at least one of them was white, thereby counting as the first white ball that was drawn? Or does it mean we have identified the two white balls before the drawing, calling one "first" and the other "second," and $B_1$ is the event that one of the two balls drawn is the white ball called "first"?

Comment: The event that no black balls are drawn is **not** complementary to the event that all three black balls are drawn. "No black balls" is complementary to "one or more black balls."

Comment: I interpret “first white ball drawn“ as : "of the two balls extracted the first must be a white one" .What should be the probability of P(“one or more black balls”)?

Comment: It's easier to compute P(no black balls). You must first draw one of the four balls that are not black on the first draw. Probability $4/7.$ Then, on the second draw you must draw one of the remaining three balls that are not black. Probability $3/6,$ given that the first ball drawn was not black. The probability of no black balls is therefore $(4/7)(3/6).$